# How can I call @wire(getListUi) method on button click?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to implement a refresh button in one of my components. I'm using the @wire decorator with getListUi to get a list of records for each of which I'm rendering a component. The @wire method calls when the component is mounted, but I also want to call it when I hit a reload button in the UI. Any idea how to achieve this? Here is what I have so far: (Not working)

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getListUi } from 'lightning/uiListApi';
import CONTENT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Content_Item__c';

export default class DayCards extends LightningElement {
    @track contentItems;
    @track error;

    @wire(getListUi, {objectApiName: CONTENT_OBJECT, listViewId: '00B9A000001AitaUAC' })
    wiredContent({error, data}) {
        if (data) {
            this.contentItems = data.records.records;
            console.log('data: ', data.records.records);
        } else if (error) {
            console.log('error: ', error);
        }
    }

    reloadItems(event) {
        console.log('refreshing');
        this.wiredContent(); // I want to call the @wire method again here
    }

}
```

---

```
<template>
    <div class="day-cards slds-p-around_medium slds-box slds-box_small">
        <div if:true={error}>{error}</div>
        <div class="refresh-button">
            <lightning-button-icon icon-name="action:refresh" variant="bare" alternative-text="Refresh" icon-class="slds-m-around_medium"
                onclick={reloadItems}></lightning-button-icon>
        </div>
        <template for:each={contentItems} for:item="item">
            <c-day-card key={item.fields.Id.value} date={item.fields.Date__c.value} description={item.fields.Description__c.value}
                link-url={item.fields.Redirect_URL__c.value}></c-day-card>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getListUi` from `lightning/uiListApi` doesn't support imperative refresh or invocation in Spring 19. That wire adapter is in beta for the Spring 19 release (per https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_lightning_ui_api_list_ui).

We're actively working on a feature whereby Lightning Data Service (and all of its `@wire` adapters) will automatically provision a new version of records when they're changed in any technology: LWC, Aura, Visualforce, Apex, triggers, etc. This means your components are reactive to record data changes regardless of the source. It also eliminates your need as a developer to know when to refresh which records. There's an open pilot for this; contact your account / support manager to join the *Live Records* pilot. We also have some other changes coming that'll make working with lists of records in LWC easier.

In the meantime you could replace your use of `getListUi` with Apex and SOQL, and use `refreshApex` from `@salesforce/apex` to imperatively refresh the Apex `@wire` adapter as required. See the code sample at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.apex.

Comment: So in other words it can only be used with hardcoded list views and sobject types? How is that even useful?

Comment: @dzh you don’t have to use the schema imports; see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about. That explains the benefit and tradeoff of schema imports.

Comment: @KevinVenkiteswaran any update on this? I have getListUi working with wire, but I don't have a way to refresh the records when the list view changes.

Comment: We had to re-approach the problem from another angle. We're working to expose an `<adapter>NotifyChange(...)`  function for each wire adapter. We've trialed this with `getRecordNotifyChange()` which is documented at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_get_record_notify. I expected other adapters to see a comparable function in the next couple of releases.  Support for `getListUi` will come later after some much-needed refactoring.

Answer (score 2):

You can just imperatively call refreshApex as explained in the docs:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.apex

```
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
refreshApex(wiredProperty)
```

Comment: I believe refreshApex is intended for cache busting, and will only work if the Apex method is annotated with cacheable=true. Tushar's suggestion of calling the Apex method imperatively would work in any scenario.

Answer (score 2):

If the above method didn't work for you. Then you can call apex method imperatively

```
handleLoad() {
        getListUi({objectApiName: CONTENT_OBJECT, listViewId: '00B9A000001AitaUAC' })
            .then(result => {

            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
            });
    }
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.apex

Comment: Hi Tushar, @Tushar Sharma, I have a similar probem , that i am trying to figure out.Would be able to help please.https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/297558/reload-a-child-component-based-on-onclick-action-event-from-parent-in-lightning/297560#297560

Answer (score 1):

You can change the value of any argument to the `getListUi` api and it will automatically call the wire method again. 
To elaborate on this, as mentioned in the documentation: [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_get_list_ui) 
The `getListUi` can take any of the following parameters:

1. objectApiName
2. listViewApiName
3. sortBy
4. pageSize
5. pageToken

Now if you change the value of any 1 variable that is assigned to these parameters the `getListUi` will automatically be triggered to fetch the new results.
Considering the usecase mentioned in the question, it seems that the **objectApiName, listViewApiName** will be constant. Hence as a workaround, you can try changing the value of variables holding the **pageSize or sortBy** to retrigger the fetch of records.
**Note: This is useful when we need to fetch different listviews of different objects and changing pageSize or sortBy will only serve as a workaround.**

Sample code:

```
pageSize = 10;
selectedObject = 'Account';
selectedListView = 'All';

@wire(getListUi, {
    objectApiName: '$selectedObject',
    listViewApiName: '$selectedListView',
    pageSize: '$pageSize',
    pageToken: '$pageToken'
})
wiredlistView(result) {
    if (result.data) {
        // do somethings
    } else if (result.error) {
        // do something
    }
}

handleButtonClick() {
    this.pageSize = 11; //will call getListUi again
}
```

Comment: Could you please expand your answer a little to explain how this could help to resolve the original problem?

Comment: I have elaborated my answer