# refreshApex on Account detail page change

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a lwc component that used apex controller on account page when the account updated, my component is not refreshing with latest data updated on account. Is there any listener available in lwc?

handleUpdate() something like?

Code:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from "lwc";
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import getAccount from "@salesforce/apex/AccountHealthCheckController.getAccount";
refreshApex(this.account); //ERROR
refreshApex(getAccount); //ERROR
export default class AccountHealthChecklwc extends LightningElement {
 @api recordId;
  @track account;
  @track error;
@wire(getAccount, { accountId: "$recordId" })
  wiredGetAccount({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
      this.error = undefined;
      this.validationMessages( data );
      console.log(this.summary);
    } else if (error) {
      this.error = error;
      this.account = undefined;
    }
  }

 validationMessages( value ) {
  this.account = value;

  //LOGIC
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: To clarify, you've a LWC named Health Check which displays data from an account record which is displayed in its standard detail page. And that you want to refresh the Health Check LWC whenever there's a change on the account record, is that right? If that's the case, then please [edit your question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/253736/edit) to reflect this ask appropriately and also take a look at [how to ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to get help. We will also need to see the code you have in Health Check. I would think you need to use LDS here.

Comment: @JayantDas updated code

Comment: What you are asking is not possible as of today as far as I can say. Take a look at [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/245274/54851) where in future having LDS will work and it will refresh the details based on any record change. In the meantime, you will need to imperatively call your apex method as linked in the comment above by Pranay.

Comment: As @JayantDas mentioned you should use imperative Apex. Basically your use case - refresh on every change - doesn't map to what '@wire' is defined for. Also: is your Apex method getting data from a single record? In that case I HIGHLY recommend that you move to using '@wire(getRecord)' (see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about), because that will be give you a lot of additional benefits once Live Record is out.

Comment: @muenzpraeger Let me rephrase my question

I have a lwc component that used apex controller on account page when the account updated my component is not refreshing. Is there any listener available in lwc? 

The class is large I can't re-do it in JS

Comment: Look up the documentation for `refreshApex`. If that's not sufficient you need, as mentioned above, to use imperative Apex. Or use a base component like `lightning-record-form`, that handles data automatically (no need for Apex or JavaScript).